# Excel 2019 not opening CSV correctly - not parsing columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

When I open a CSV files in Excel 2019 the file is not being parsed correctly. When I opened the same files in Excel 2016 they would be parsed correctly, with the commas used as delimiters. But I have just installed Excel 2019 and it is opening files without recognizing that they are CSV.

I am not trying to import data from a CSV file I opening it directly. This always worked just fine. And I thought that 2019 would be better with CSVs.

Here's an example file samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv

How can I tell excel that a CSV file is a CSV file?!?! Is there an option somewhere? I don't want to use the "import data" option, it should work automatically.

[image]

Comment: It was this answer, the separator in regional settings, damn MS!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021203/2319308

Comment: You could also use Text to Columns using , as the delimiter.

Comment: @spikey_richie not a practical solution if I have thousands of files.

Comment: Your question doesn't state you have thousands of files

Comment: i have started using TSV (tab seperated) instead of csv all the places i can - excel never fails importing them

Answer (score 3):

Check your system separator in Excel > File > Options > Advanced and make sure that Decimal and thousands separators are set correctly (., resp. ,).

Answer (score 3):

Seems related to this:

### Problem:

*.csv files (comma-separated) used to open as tables in Excel (automatically) but then started opening just as plain text, not tables. (and now Excel expect semicolon instead of commas -- then opens as table.)

Perhaps relates for many Excel versions, but for me seems this happened after recent upgrade of Excel in Office365 on OSX - to Excel 16.31 19111002

### Debug:

On Windows there is explicit "List separator" setting in the Region / Language:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953679/how-to-correctly-display-csv-files-within-excel-2013/37021203#37021203

but this one seems hidden somewhere in **MacOS / OSX** (i.e. there is not explicit "List separator" setting (or some similar parameter)). This seems to be set in OSX when you're changing your REGION / COUNTRY. (Apparently Excel expects that in German-speaking countries people use semi-colon instead of comma in *.CSV files: http://forum.provue.com/t/using-semicolons-instead-of-commas-in-european-format-csv-files/2780/11)

It does not help to just changing settings like "Number separators - Grouping / Decimal" settings in System Preferences > Language & Region > Advanced ..

### HELPED:

Changed Region to UK/US, but then tweaked all settings back to normal:
1. System Preferences > Language & Region > set to "UK" (or US)
2. Customize System Preferences > Language & Region > Advanced.. -- changing there Number / Decimal / Currency / Measurement units to the ones you have in your real country.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out the problem is in your Regional Settings, and you need to change the List separator in Windows to a comma. Another option, in case you are generating the file, is to use a semi-colon as a delimiter.