# Excel Automatically split text to columns. How do I turn that off?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When opening a CSV file, excel automatically splits text to columns. However, Since I work in an international environment, the delimiter is not always the same. Meaning sometimes it goes well, but many times excel screws up the document to a point where it gets completely unusable.

Is there a way to turn this functionality completely off. I rather use the function manually, so I can select the correct delimiters myself.

Comment: Good Day, This isn't a solution, but this older post might provide some guidance. https://superuser.com/questions/238944/how-to-force-excel-to-open-csv-files-with-data-arranged-in-columns

Comment: AFAIK, you can't turn it off. You can either reset it (by running it on a cell but deselecting all the delimiters), or you can **Import** the csv file, instead of **Open**ing it. The TTC wizard will default to the last settings used.  Importing a csv file gives you far more control over what is happening; and avoids problems not only with changing delimiters, but also with changing date formats, decimals, and thousands separators.

Comment: You can try to open a blank Workbook first and then import csv to Workbook: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Answer (score 1):

If you have concerns about how Excel will open your file, don't double-click it to open it. Instead, use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Text/CSV.

In that wizard, you can select the delimiter you prefer to use for that file.

[image]

Comment: The files are usually opened directly from other programs or web interfaces. So this is why I just need the fuction to automatically split Text to Columns completely Off.

Comment: Make sure you have created a blank workbook/sheet first else you will find the options disabled